# App insight query to get result for each id and category mapping with number of count

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

```
Event 1
Custom Event
Prop1- abc
customDimensions
  ID - [4,6,11] //multiple id’s
  Category- Q //can be one of P,Q,R,S

Event 2
Custom Event
Prop1- abc
customDimensions
  ID - [10,11,25,2] //multiple id’s
  Category- Q //can be one of P,Q,R,S

Event 3
Custom Event
Prop1- abc
customDimensions
  ID - [11,9,26,8] //multiple id’s
  Category- R //can be one of P,Q,R,S
```

These are application insight events,
I'm looking for result records as below in 3 columns mapped for each ID, Category, and count

```
ID - Category - count
11 - Q - 2
11 - R - 1
4 - Q - 1
6 - Q - 1
26 - R - 1
....
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App insight query to get record which have more than one record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71867287/app-insight-query-to-get-record-which-have-more-than-one-record)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. Also, do mind that, in order to attract answers, it is appreciated if you mentioned what you have tried already with some kusto code for example. Your best bet is to start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuremonitor). The customEvents table doesn't have props like `Category` so how exactly is it stored assuming it is somewhere in the `customDimensions` field?

Comment: This is a workaround I'm trying to achieve to the question I already posted. I tried but was not able to put those ids in a column. Yes, it is under customDimensions, it would be great if you could help me here.

Comment: @PeterBons - updated question with 'customDimensions' tree

Comment: Can you post an example of the value in customDimensions?

Comment: Use a datable operator to supply a data sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Comment: i tried `mv-expand split(customDimensions_ID,',') `  and got count for each ID by splitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [posted by the asker in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916544/app-insight-query-to-get-result-for-each-id-and-category-mapping-with-number-of/72096084#comment127093869_71916544), here is the syntax which we need to use to expand the CustomDimensions into columns:

> ```
> mv-expand split(customDimensions_ID,',')
> ```

Check [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator for more information.